# Why were my permissions different from the default and what are the implications of "fixing" them?

Tags: macos, permission, recovery

For some time now my Finder "Get Info" dialogs have been [displaying "Fetching..."](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20121641-263/file-group-permissions-constantly-displaying-fetching..-in-os-x/), and I recently decided to fix the problem by following the instructions for [resetting my home folder permissions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42974/4395). As expected, this resolved the issue, but now the permissions on all of my files are

```
-rw-r-----   1 MyName  staff   ... FileNow
```

whereas before they were

```
-rw-r-----   1 MyName  MyName  ... FileBefore
```

and I wonder: Why were they different before? Is there some common operation that causes permissions to change from the default, to what I had? Was the default [perhaps different in earlier versions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28546/proper-group-id-gid-for-lion) of OS X? Are there [security implications of this change](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63847/9297)?

Comment: Note that `staff` isn't even a group I'm in (I'm in `admin`). I'm not sure what the implications of that are, or who ends up in that group.

Comment: that is because you have admin rights. a normal user is in staff

Comment: ALso note that the Apple note to rename users only includes OSs up to Lion - so not ML - take note of what details are on a article - I don't know what if anything ML has changed or if the note just has not een updated..

Comment: @Mark: Good point. I followed [these](http://osxdaily.com/2011/11/15/repair-user-permissions-in-mac-os-x-lion/) (same) instructions, which mentioned ML explicitly.